# Google Apps Script server error when trying to add an editor to a Google Document

Tags: google-apps-script

I have some code that looks like this

```
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(/* destination folder id */);
  var doc = DriveApp.getFileById(/* document file id */);

  var id = doc.makeCopy(folder).setName(/* name of copy */).getId();
  var new_doc = DocumentApp.openById(id);
  new_doc.addEditor(/* some email address */);
```

Running this causes the script to stop at the last line and throw this error:

> We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again.

If I comment out the line, then the script runs fine.
<s>Also if `new_doc` is a `File` instead of a `Document`, then the last line works fine too. It's only when `new_doc` is a `Document` type that it gives me an error.</s> Apparently, it doesn't work for `Document` types either. Although the error I get is different from when it's a `File`:

> Cannot use this operation on a Team Drive item.

Very weird, because this was working a while ago.

All resources used in this script (the script, the destination folder, the file that is copied, the copy, etc.) are in a Team Drive.

I am puzzled as to how or why this error is happening and I am looking for help in getting around this issue.

Comment: I am facing the same issue with a Form bound script. When trying to add an editor to my Form which is in Team Drive, I am receiving the error: "We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again". Have you had any luck on a solution since earlier this month?

Answer (score 0):

Add the editor through the DriveApp as opposed to the DocumentApp.

It appears to be a bug with DocumentApp, SpreadsheetApp and FormApp when working with Team Drive files.

```
var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(/* destination folder id */);
var doc = DriveApp.getFileById(/* document file id */);

var id = doc.makeCopy(folder).setName(/* name of copy */).getId();
var new_doc = DriveApp.getFileById(id); //updated this from DocumentApp to DriveApp.
new_doc.addEditor(/* some email address */);
```